# Are sub addresses implemented yet?

Tags: sub-address

I can't figure out if we already have sub addresses working. If so, is there a guide on how to generate and use them? If not, is there an ETA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not implemented and integrated into master branch yet, see here:

https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/2056

Answer (score 1):

The [pull request](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/2056) is merged now and you can use them with the address command as described in [this answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/8124/how-do-i-create-a-subaddress-with-the-cli-wallet).