# How do I create a subaddress with the cli wallet?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, sub-address

With Lithium Luna v0.12 sub-addresses were added.

How do I create and manage sub-addresses that I can use to enhance my privacy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new cli command is called address.

```
address [ new <label text with white spaces allowed> | all | <index_min> 
[<index_max>] | label <index> <label text with white spaces allowed>]
```

To create a new sub-address for the current account use `address new`.
You can view all addresses with the `address all` command.

[image: Example sub-address creation]

Each sub-address will get an index starting with 1 since the primary account address is at index 0.

You can also add a label to each sub-address as optional parameter or later with the label option.

Edit:
If you want to see balance on the sub-addresses you can use the command "balance detail" on the cli.

Comment: Can you rename a label?